# How to convert Seconds to Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have to convert seconds to time format:

```js
seconds_1 = 540;
seconds_2 = -2820;

convert_1 = new Date(seconds_1 * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
convert_2 = new Date(seconds_2 * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);

console.log(convert_1);
console.log(convert_2);
```

it will return,

```
convert_1  : 00:09:00
convert_2 : 23:13:00
```

first one (convert_1) is correct, but the second one should return  `-00:47:00` .

The Actual issue is, the negative value is not converting to time correctly.

Please help.

I tried this,

```js
   function toTime(duration) {   
      // Hours, minutes and seconds
      var hrs = ~~(duration / 3600);
      var mins = ~~((duration % 3600) / 60);
      var secs = ~~duration % 60;
      let ret = hrs+ ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
      return ret;
    }

seconds_1 = 540;
seconds_2 = -2820;

console.log(toTime(seconds_2 ));
```

Comment: The `Date` object isn't the right tool for this, your best bet is to just divide the value up into seconds, minutes, and hours, convert those to strings padding with `0` as necessary, and then combine them into a string manually.

Comment: There is no such time as `-00:47:00` - do you mean convert seconds to minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test

```js
const convert = secs => { 
  const sign = secs < 0
  const hhmmss = new Date(Math.abs(secs) * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  return sign ? '-' + hhmmss : hhmmss
}  
  

console.log(convert(540));
console.log(convert(-2820));
```

Answer (score 3):

A pragmatic solution is to remove the sign and then add it again:

```js
function toTime(seconds) {
    if (seconds < 0) return "-" + toTime(-seconds);
    return new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

console.log(toTime(540));
console.log(toTime(-2820));
```

Comment: Nice one.......